# Changing svg to a different color where it stays

Tags: javascript, css, svg

How would I change the play svg color on click, where it stays and doesn’t change back to the previous color it was before?

**How it would work:**

I click the svg, the video opens up, home button is clicked.

The Home button is the **X**

svg Button that was previously clicked is now a different color than it was before.

That’s what I am trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/eq0ohp78/

```js
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

  function showHidden() {
    const theHides = document.querySelectorAll(".hide");
    theHides.forEach(function needsAName(removeHide) {
      removeHide.classList.remove("hide");
    });

  }

  function showBody() {
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theBody.classList.remove("bg1");
  }

  function showActive() {
    const theActive = document.querySelector(".with-curtain.active");
    theActive.classList.remove("active");
    showHidden();
    showBody();
  }

  function homeClickHandler() {
    showActive();
  }

  function addClickToHome(goHome) {
    goHome.forEach(function addHandler(goHome) {
      goHome.addEventListener("click", homeClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    const goHome = document.querySelectorAll(".home");
    addClickToHome(goHome);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function showBody() {
    const theBody = document.querySelector("body");
    theBody.classList.add("bg1");
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
    showBody();
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function addHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

function combinePlayerOptions(options1 = {}, options2 = {}) {
  const combined = Object.assign({}, options1, options2);
  Object.keys(options1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
    if (typeof options1[prop] === "object") {
      combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, options1[prop], options2[prop]);
    }
  });
  return combined;
}

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function createStopHandler(player) {
    const stopButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".home");
    stopButtons.forEach(function addHandler(buttons) {
      buttons.addEventListener("click", function stopHandler() {
        player.stopVideo();
      });
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    createStopHandler(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings) {
    const defaults = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    defaults.events = {
      onReady: onPlayerReady
    };

    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    players.push(player);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const defaults = {
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      enablejsapi: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3
    }
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerOptions) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer
  };

}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  managePlayer.add(".playa", {});

  managePlayer.add(".playb", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  managePlayer.add(".playc", {});

  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });

  manageUI.init({});

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}

.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

body.bg1{
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
}
body.bg1:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  /*z-index: 1;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 10px, #0000 10px 160px, black 160px),
    linear-gradient(orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 15px, #0000 15px 155px, orange 155px),
    linear-gradient(black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 20px, #0000 20px 150px, black 150px),
    linear-gradient(teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 25px, #0000 25px 145px, teal 145px),
    linear-gradient(black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 30px, #0000 30px 140px, black 140px),
    linear-gradient(orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 35px, #0000 35px 135px, orange 135px),
    linear-gradient(black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 40px, #0000 40px 130px, black 130px),
    linear-gradient(teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 45px, #0000 45px 125px, teal 125px),
    linear-gradient(black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 50px, #0000 50px 120px, black 120px),
    linear-gradient(orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 55px, #0000 55px 115px, orange 115px),
    linear-gradient(black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 60px, #0000 60px 110px, black 110px),
    linear-gradient(teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, teal 65px, #0000 65px 105px, teal 105px),
    linear-gradient(black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 70px, #0000 70px 100px, black 100px),
    linear-gradient(orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, orange 75px, #0000 75px 95px, orange 95px),
    linear-gradient(black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 80px, #0000 80px 90px, black 90px),
    linear-gradient(teal, teal);
}

.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.playa,
.playb,
.playc {
  margin: auto 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

.playa {
  fill: red;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playb {
  fill: blue;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.playc {
  fill: orange;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.home {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  fill: red;
  padding: 0;
}

.homesvg {
  fill: none;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 17.80202103;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  border: 4.625px solid #4e4e4e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.curtain2 .panel-left::before,
.curtain2 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.curtain3 .panel-left::before,
.curtain3 .panel-right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open" pointer-events="none">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g id="play">
          <title>Play</title>
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
          <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>

            <button class="home" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="homesvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g id="home">
            <title>Home</title>

            <path d="M 6.3895625,6.4195626 C 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437" />
            <path d="M 6.3894001,93.6106 C 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="home" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="homesvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#home" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container with-curtain">
        <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
        <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="wrapa">
                    <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-left"></div>
                <div class="panel-right"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="home" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="homesvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#home" />
        </svg>
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the lines where you have `addClickToButtons` function like below and it worked for me:

```
function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
  playButtons.forEach(function addHandler(playButton) {
    playButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
       coverClickHandler(e);
       playButton.style.fill = 'white';
    });
  });
}
```